# Count the occurrences of a boolean operation

Tags: uml, ocl

I have to make an OCL rule saying that two parameters cannot be equal. I cannot use the `not()` so I have to show that something like `param1 = param2` is empty.

I tried to use `isEmpty()` and `size()` but as it's `boolean`, these operators don't work

```
self.ab1.ab2
->forAll(x | x.b1.b2
->forAll(port | (self.param1 = port.param2)->isEmpty())

 )
```

I think I have to use some kind of `count()` operator that needs to be equal to 0 to show that param1 and param2 are different but I don't know how to use it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your direct question, use of `<>` and so `self.param1 <> port.param2` would seem appropriate. However doing a doubly nested forAll starting in some context seems unhelpful. If you cannot move the 'constraint' to a better context perhaps you can at least be clearer by:
    `self.ab1.ab2.b1.b2.param2->asSet()->excludes(self.param2)`